# Where are the QGIS Style Manager settings stored?

Tags: qgis, style, icon

I would like to export all the icons defined in QGIS Style Manager to another QGIS installation in another PC.

[image]

I've been looking in Windows Registry inside "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\QGIS" but I did not find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [OSGeo.org forum](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/symbology-ng-style-db-and-symbology-ng-style-xml-td5046097.html), the styles are saved in your `.qgis2` directory as an sqlite db file:

```
.qgis2/symbology-ng-style.db
```

Initially it was saved as an .xml file but this is no longer the case.